# Perl Detect Handles for Permission Denied Error While Opening File

Tags: perl

I am debugging a large perl (5.10.1) script that sometimes has trouble opening a file for write access on Windows server 2012 R2.  I get a permission denied error, even though the perl script was run in an administrator command prompt and the only things which should be touching the file it is trying to open are the script itself or other instances of it (the script is run several times in a row).  The only thing I can think is that there is a handle that is sometimes not closed properly.  Is there any way to debug this and see what was prevent the file from being overwritten, or is combing through the code by hand the only way?  Are there other reasons for permission denied than open handles or a non-privileged user account?

Comment: Show your open statement and the die.

Comment: If that duplicate doesn't answer your question, let me know in a comment here and I will reopen the question for you.

Comment: I was looking for something that could detect the handles at the time I try to open the file in the perl script.  Process explorer only updates twice a second and don't seem to show the perl program which is running.  Procmon might work except it runs out of memory trying to filter everything and makes to compiler go at a crawl.